# Is it okay to use lambda as a default non-type template argument to generate unique types?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

```cpp
template <auto = [](){}>
struct A;

using unique_1 = A<>;
using unique_2 = A<>;
```

Is it safe to generate unique types like that or that's some sort of ill-formed behaviour?

Comment: It certainly seems to work on all 3 major compilers : https://godbolt.org/z/rbPaPcerr they all agree unique_1 and unique_2 are different types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas are never structural types and therefore trying to use a closure type of a lambda as a non-type template parameter's type is ill-formed. This has been clarified by [CWG issue 2542](https://wg21.link/cwg2542).

So the question of whether or not the template-ids `A<>` refer to different specializations becomes irrelevant.

Compilers might not implement the defect report yet.

However, by the current standard rules the following is possible:

```
template<typename = void>
using A = decltype([]{});

using unique_1 = A<>;
using unique_2 = A<>;
```

There is an open CWG issue on the subject of changing this, because the rule permitting this behavior was intended to make it so that `A<int>` and `A<float>` are different types, not that every mention of `A<int>` will be a different type. That would seriously mess with ODR between translation units. Also there is compiler divergence. See [CWG issue 2794](https://wg21.link/cwg2794).

Comment: What do you think about [this paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.6)? Is it applicable if a lambda were a structural type? Or in your second example?

Comment: @cppbest No, I don't think so. The specific meaning of that point isn't very clear to me anyway. But taking the examples in the following note as a guideline, I don't think it would apply.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have gone into whether lambdas as non-type template args are okay. This is interesting, but even if they're not, you could just do this:

```cpp
template<typename Identity = decltype([](){})>
struct A;

using unique_1 = A<>;
using unique_2 = A<>;
```

The more interesting question is whether this is a good way to generate unique types.

I can't give you a "language-lawyer" answer, but I can answer from experience trying to use the same idea myself. The answer was: if you do it within one single translation unit it works fine. Once you put it into a header included by multiple compilation units unexpected things might happen, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5PvbTTbnG).

To explain the code: Common.hpp defines the unique types and declares a templated method. TL1 explicitly specializes this templated method for `unique_1`, and TL2 calls this templated method. This works fine when using an inline struct for the type identity, but when using the decltype of the lambda the linker doesn't find the explicit specialization. Moreover, the compiler warns that it's not used in TL1, meaning it seems to treat it like a local symbol (ie in an anonymous namespace). Interestingly, typeid returns the same name and hash for the types in both translation units. So I'm guessing there's some undefined/implementation defined behavior going on.

If someone can actually explain why this is happening I'd be very interested myself.

Comment: If every appearance of the template-id refers to a specialization with a different closure type as template argument, then it is only logical that two template-ids in different translation units also are different types and that they behave as if they had internal linkage. The alternative would be that they always refer to the same closure type. The name and hash returned by `typeid` are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: It's not clear what you expected... Once the code in the header files are included in the compilation units, you end up with two different lambdas, hence two different definitions of the templates. The fact that the hash code is the same for the types does not prove anything: the only guarantee is that same types have the same hash code, but different types do not need to have different hash codes.

Comment: Good point about the hash not having to be unique. Other than that, I think it's not obvious that this behavior would occur. It makes sense, but without trying it I would have not felt confident in predicting it. In the end, I'm just trying to answer the question "is this a good way to generate unique types". And I think the effect I demonstrated is very relevant to that.